# How to do async in quasar before rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

In my vue app, I want the contents of a meta tag to be the result of a network request.  To get this done, I'm learning quasar to make my app partially SSR, but I can't figure out how to run something async before a server-side render completes.

Here's a little MRE that isolates the problem.  I try to delay with a promise, then set a value in the `metaData` below....

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useMeta } from 'quasar'

const metaData = {
  // sets document title
  title: 'title initial value',

  // optional; sets final title as "Index Page - My Website", useful for multiple level meta
  titleTemplate: title => `The title is: ${title}`,

  // meta tags
  meta: {
    // note: for Open Graph type metadata you will need to use SSR, to ensure page is rendered by the server
    ogTitle: {
      property: 'og:title',
      // optional; similar to titleTemplate, but allows templating with other meta properties
      template (ogTitle) {
        return `${ogTitle} - My OG Website`
      }
    }
  }
}

const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

export default defineComponent({
  async beforeCreate () {
    await delay(3000)
    // I want this to be in the rendered page
    metaData.title = 'title, initialized after a delay'
  },
  setup () {
    useMeta(metaData)
  },
  name: 'IndexPage'
})
</script>
```

I've proven that `beforeCreate` is being executed, but I think what's happening is that it returns a promise on the `await`, and the SSR just plows ahead. The initial value for `title` ends up in the client's  tag, instead of the one I want.

Is there a way I can use SSR but do some async work before rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to handle asynchronous data in a server-side rendered Vue app is to use the `asyncData` method.
This method is called before the server-side render occurs. It allows you to perform asynchronous operations.

For example:

```js
export default {
    async asyncData({ params, $http }) {
      const post = await $http.$get(`https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${params.id}`)
      return { post }
    }
  }
```

You can use the `asyncData` method in Quasar by setting the `ssr: true` option in your Quasar app's `quasar.conf.js` file. You can then use the `asyncData` method in your Vue components as shown in the example above.

More info: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can you explain a little more about `ssr: true`? In my quasar config file, ssr is an object with values like `ssr: { pwa: false, prodPort: 3000, middleware: ['render']}`. Are you suggesting that I replace this object with `false`?

Comment: Bounty is almost expired, so I will award it. This has not worked for me, but thanks anyway. Maybe you can help me.  changed  to `ssr: false` but I always see the unchanged title on the client.  I also have trouble seeing any server console.log. Any idea how to do that?